# Using DAO type library in Delphi XE7 shows errors in IDE

Tags: delphi, ide, dao, typelib

I have a Delphi XE7 application that imports the Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library (DAO_TLB).  Any references to objects and properties for DAO are flagged as errors even though the application compiles and executes just fine.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: Tobject);
var
    DBEngine    : _DBEngine;
    DB          : Database;
begin
   DBEngine := CoDBEngine.Create;
   DB := DBEngine.OpenDatabase('test.mdb', false, false, '');
end;
```

Gives the following errors in the IDE:

```
Undeclared identifier '_DBEngine' at ...
Undeclared identifier 'Database' at ...
Undeclared identifier 'CoDBEngine' at ...
etc.
```

I end up with hundreds of error messages.

The program compiles and runs fine and code completion correctly shows the available properties for the objects.

Is there something I'm doing wrong here? Is there a way to suppress these error messages?

Comment: You've done nothing wrong. Error Insight (the cause of those spurious errors) is totally buggy, and has been for years. It uses a totally separate compiler that simply can't properly track declarations. The solution I use (and have with every version of Delphi since Error Insight was introduced) is to simply disable it in *Tools->Options->Editor Options->Code Insight*.

Comment: That probably will work fine for me.  I just found it annoying.  I get similar issues just looking at the DAO_TLB file itself. I get nonsensical errors that point to the comment block at the head of the file.  Just wanted some confirmation.  I appreciate the feedback.